# regions in cadence

Tags: dc, oscillator, oscillation, cadence

I have a circuit that in it mosfets go through different regions (the circuits's core is an oscillator, I quench my oscillator by some mechanism and then let it oscillate again till the amplitude of the oscillation reaches a threshold, compare the envelope of the oscillation to a reference and eventually create pulses and apply them to gates of the mosfets controlling the tail current of my complementary cross-coupled oscillator). when I print the DC operating points in spectre-rf and look at the regions printed, what is that region showing me then? and also the other DC parameters like vgs?

Comment: Show us what you're looking at.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "different regions". Do you mean saturation vs linear (triode) mode? If so you will not see that in the simulator.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes, I mean saturation versus linear.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out that all that is shown as the Dc parameters like: id, vgs, vth, vds, ... are the parameters of the **start** of the cycle.

Comment: You should **edit** your question with this information, and not add it in an **answer** like you did now. Please copy-paste the text to the question and **delete** this answer.